# How to assign from input to object from a class

Tags: python, input, eval

I have multiple classes and I have instances from each class e.g: Student class. every instance (a student) has their own courses. Now when a user signs in (by input) I want to print their list of courses. Or even just their age to show that I have the correct object.

Is there a better way than `eval()` to get an object from class based on `input`
like the following example:

```
class Student:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self._name = name
    self._age = age

blablue = Student('bla blue', '23')
name = input('enter your name')
name = name.split(' ')
stundent = eval(name[0] + name[1])
print(student)
print(student.age)
```

output:

```
enter your name: bla blue
<__main__.Foo object at 0x000001B2978C73C8>
23
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It seems that you want to choose a class instance by using the user input. Maybe you should provide some more context, as this particular solution seems not very pythonic to me.

Comment: You could store all the classes in a dictionary by name. But there's probably a better answer if we have more context.

Comment: I'm practicing OOP and I want to use the instance attributes based on which object the user will input.

Comment: So you want to take the input for name and put that inside Foo and then print Foo's name?

Comment: I can already answer the first part of the question : there is ALWAYS a "better solution than `eval()`" - specially when working on unsanitized user inputs. Now what the "better solution" is depends on the context, which you didn't really provide, but a `dict`(as suggested by JETM - even if he should have wrote "instances" instead of "classes" -) is probably the simplest thing that could work.

Comment: I have multiple classes and I have instances from each class e.g: Student class.
every instance-student- has his own courses. Now when user sign in(by input) I want to print his list of courses.

Comment: thanks, JETM. this was what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is for educational purpose (production code would use a SQL database and some ORM):

```
try:
    # python 2.x
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    # python 3.x
    pass


class AlreadyExists(ValueError):
    pass


class DoesNotExist(LookupError):
    pass


class FooCollection(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._foos = {}

    def add(self, foo):
        if foo.name in self._foos:
            raise AlreadyExists("Foo with name '{}' already exists".format(foo.name))
        self.update(foo)

    def update(self, foo):
        self._foos[foo.name] = foo    

    def get(self, name):
        try:
            return self._foos[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise DoesNotExist("no Foo named '{}'".format(name))


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self._name = name
        self._age = age

    # we at least need to be able to read the name   
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Foo({}, {})".format(self._name, self._age)


def main():
    foos = FooCollection()     
    blablue = Foo('bla blue', '23')
    foos.add(blablue)

    name = input('enter your name: ').strip()
    try:
        print("found {}".format(foos.get(name)))
    except DoesNotExist as e:
        print(e)

if ___name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The principle here is to have a storage for your instances. I chose a `dict` for fast lookup with the `Foo.name` as key, in real life you'd probably want an opaque unique identifier for each instance and multiple indexes (i.e. one by id, one by name etc) - but actually in real life you would use a SQL database that already provide all those features in a much more optimized way ;-)

Also, I wrapped the `dict` in a dedicated class with its own interface. This allows to decouple the interface from the implementation (if you later decide you want more indexes than just `name` for example), and encapsulate domain logic too (i.e. checking you don't accidentally overwrite an existing `Foo`).